# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql_2.sock' during manual installation of mysql

Tags: mysql

I get the error below when attempting to manually install `mysql-5.6.17-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64`

Steps I followed:

```
1. tar -xzvf mysql-standard-5.1.34-linux-i686-glibc23.tar.gz
2. ln -s mysql-standard-5.1.34-linux-i686-glibc23 mysql
 a) set basedir= to the full path of your new mysql directory
 b) set datadir= to the full path of the /data subdir in your new mysql directory.
3. Set up the default MySQL databases:
 a) ./scripts/mysql_install_db --defaults-file=mysql.cnf
 b) ./bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=mysql.cnf -u root password "yourpasswordhere"
4. Create a New Database and User Account
 a) Log in to your mysql server as root: ./bin/mysql --defaults-file=mysql.cnf -u root -p
```

mysql.cnf file looks like:

```
[client]
socket=/tmp/mysql_2.sock
port=3307
####################################
[mysqld]
#REQUIRED!!
#Change the basedir directory to reflect your mysql home directory
basedir=/mysql
#REQUIRED!!
#Change the data direcory to reflect your mysql data directory
datadir=/mysql/data
port=3307
socket=/tmp/mysql_2.sock
key_buffer_size=64M

#[OPTIMIZATION]
#Set this value to 50% of available RAM if your environment permits.
myisam_sort_buffer_size=1.5G
#[OPTIMIZATION]
#This value should be at least 50% of free hard drive space. Use caution if         setting it to 100% of free space however. Your hard disk may fill up!
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

#[OPTIMIZATION]
#Our default of 2G is probably fine for this value. Change this value only if you are using a machine with little resources available. 
read_buffer_size=1.5G
```

command:

```
root@ubuntu:/mysql#  ./bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-    file=mysql.cnf &
```

Error:

```
[1] 2386
root@ubuntu:/mysql# 140415 19:08:12 mysqld_safe Logging to '/mysql/data/ubuntu.err'.
chown: invalid user: `mysql'  
140415 19:08:12 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from     /mysql/data
140415 19:08:12 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file     /mysql/data/ubuntu.pid ended  

./bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=mysql.cnf -u   
./bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=mysql.cnf -u root password 12345
./bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed  

error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql_2.sock' (2)' 

Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql_2.sock' exists!
[1]+  Done                    ./bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=mysql.cnf
```

I tried to login by command:

```
./bin/mysql --defaults-file=mysql.cnf -u root -p
```

Error:

```
Enter password:   

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql_2.sock' (2)
```

Comment: "Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql_2.sock' exists!"

Comment: You need to tell us what you've done to install it. For example, you seem not to have created the `mysql` user who is apparently needed: `chown: invalid user: `mysql'`

Comment: @Rinzwind '/tmp/mysql_2.sock' does not exist. How to check is mysqld working?

Comment: @terdon I am trying to create a New Database and User Account. login to it and create a new schema.

Comment: @nari2 that should be a question you should not need to ask. `ps -ef | grep mysql` would be my choice. By the way: if the socket is not created you probably have permissions problems.

Comment: I realize, I mean how you installed the ``./bin/mysqld_safe`, what steps you carried out for that. Also, why not just install `mysql` normally, from the repositories? In any case, you will need to create a `mysql` user to be able to run the `mysql` service.

Comment: @terdon I added next step for login in my question. have a look.

Comment: Thanks, but it's the _previous_ steps that are missing. You seem to have downloaded a `mysql` package or source tarball or something from somewhere but you have not explained where or how you installed it. What we need to see is what made `./bin/mysqld_safe`. Also, as I said in my two previous comments, you need to create a `mysql` user, that's the first error you are getting. I (well, we, I am not any kind of mysql expert) want to see the steps you followed to know if you did so and if anything else is missing.

Comment: @terdon I followed instructions from **orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9/doc/OrthoMCLEngine/Main/mysqlInstallationGuide.txt** from [this link](http://orthomcl.org/common/downloads/software/v2.0/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9.tar.gz)

Comment: Thanks, please include all this info in your actual question. Copy the steps you followed from the guide and include them here.

Comment: @terdon Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Add a user for your mysql server `useradd -r -s /bin/false -m -d /mysql mysql`
2. Write an [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com) script for your server.
3. Check that the `pid` file and socket files can be created by your `mysql` user by executing the proper `chmod`'s.

Comment: useradd: user 'mysql' already exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of steps to check when you do it manually that could create the error mentioned above. I will assume you either manually downloaded MySQL from the official site or used a 3rd party PPA to install it:

- Check that mysql is not already running:

  `ps -e|grep -i 'mysqld'`.

  If it appears then you need to kill it by doing a `sudo killall -9 mysqld`. In the case it does not die, then grab the PID from the `ps` you ran and `kill -9 PID`
- Run mysql via `/etc/init.d/mysql start` to see if it creates the same error. If it gives you the exact same error from above then you need to copy the `mysql.server` file which is found in the support-files folder inside the mysql folder you downloaded or in the `/usr/local/mysql` folder and you need to copy it to `/etc/init.d/mysql` eg:

  `cp mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql` and give it a executable permission chmod +x then try running `/etc/init.d/mysql start` again.
- If it still gives you a problem then you need to edit the config file in `/etc/my.cnf` and change ALL the `/tmp/mysql.socket` lines to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` or any other socket place you wish to send it. Note that the config file can also be in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in some cases like mine. The config file has at least 3 lines you need to change.

Comment: mysqld not running. /etc/init.d does not contain mysql file or folder.

Comment: There you go. Now copy the mysql server script found on the downloaded tar to the init folder and give it executable permissions. Then run it.

Answer (score 0):

If your file my.cnf (usually in the /etc/mysql/folder) is correctly configured with

```
 socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

you can check if mysql is running with the following command:

```
 mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

change your permission to mysql folder. If you are working locally, you can do:

```
 sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```